# name capture in Haskell `let` expression

Tags: haskell, let

I was writing a function something similar to this:

```
f x = let
  x = ...
  in
    e
```

Due to scoping rules in Haskell any use of x in e will resolve to the definition of x in the `let` construct.

Why is such a thing allowed in Haskell?
Shouldn't the compiler reject such a program telling we cannot bind a value that has the same name as argument of the function.

(This example may be simplistic, but in real world context where variables have semantic meaning associated with them it is easy to make such mistake)

Comment: Name / identifier / variable shadowing is generally allowed in many programming languages. If forbidden, `f x = x+1` would stop working only because someone added a global `x=42` somewhere, or only because a newer version of some imported library now exports `x`. Even in the lambda calculus `\x. \x. ...` is allowed (and this simplifies the semantics a bit). ML even allows `let x = x+1 in ...`, which is _not_ recursive in ML, which became idiomatic. Now, I'm not arguing that shadowing is good, but IMO a compiler warning for that is better than an error.

Comment: In a highly recursive language like Haskell, it might be difficult to separate accidental reuse of a variable name from intentional recursion...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid indeed. I just fixed a bug in my code with the same issue which caused an infinite loop in the program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable warnings for this type of name shadowing with the compiler flag

[`-fwarn-name-shadowing`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html#id538931)

> This option causes a warning to be emitted whenever an inner-scope value has the same name as an outer-scope value, i.e. the inner value shadows the outer one. This can catch typographical errors that turn into hard-to-find bugs, e.g., in the inadvertent capture of what would be a recursive call in f = ... let f = id in ... f ....

However, it is more common to compile with `-Wall`, which includes a lot of other warnings that will help you avoid bad practices.

Comment: Good advice! But you didn't answer the question "why is such a thing allowed in haskell?"

Comment: @LudvigH that's asking for opinion, really. I think Chad's answer answers it between the lines. If it's a warning, then Haskell/GHC creators have realized that it's potentially dangerous, but didn't feel that's necessary to forbid it entirely.

Comment: Fair enough. But I'm too often astounded by people at SO who manages to find design documents and specification which explain the line of reasoning leading up to decisions such as shadowing, so I thought such an answer would be valid and not a question of opinion.  In either case - I think Chad provides the answer to the practical question of how to deal with it.

Comment: @LudvigH, Haskell almost certainly allows it simply because it's allowed in lambda calculus and the chain of LC descendants that led to Haskell. LC itself was intended as a formal logical system rather than a programming language; Alonzo Church probably didn't even consider the potential for human error.

Comment: @LudvigH Maybe it's the other way, Nobody designed anything explicitely against name shadowing, because that would require an extra step (or effort to do). For example it's probably hard (maybe impossible) to exclude name shadowing using BNF, therefore the normal definition of a let expression allows it (until someone complains and adds it as a warning).